# mysql innodb optimize - fails after hours

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
services.profile      optimize        note    Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
services.profile      optimize        error   Creating index 'PRIMARY' required more than 'innodb_online_alter_log_max_size' bytes of modification log. Please try again.
services.profile      optimize        status  Operation failed
```

The table is 300GB large with indexes.

The variable mysql complains after working for 3 HOURS:

```
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size        5500000000
```

The table is not being written to more than a few MB in that time.

What is the problem of innodb/mysql that a simple OPTIMIZE of a 300GB table fails after 3 hours of "work" because a buffer of 5.5GB ran full ??

Comment: No diskspace problem @Bill 
temporary disk has 500 gig free storage and the database disk 700

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB tables -- it provides little, if any, benefit.

InnoDB suffers from *some* fragmentation, but not enough to be worth the downtime of defragmenting.  And the data will quickly become fragmented again.

The main cause of fragmentation is "block splits"  For example, when you add a row to a 16KB block which is 'full', the block is split into two.  The, say, 89 rows plus 1 row in one block become, say, 45 rows in each of two blocks.  As you continue to insert rows, these (and other) blocks gradually fill up until they split again.  After a lot of such inserts, the table becomes about 69% full.

So, you say, won't that slow things down a lot?  No.  Point queries drill down a BTree -- a relatively constant time.  Range scans hit more blocks, but the number of rows scanned does not change.  Etc.

Also, InnoDB will combine two adjacent blocks that are "too empty", thereby avoiding (usually) some worst case scenarios.  If you `DELETE` lots of rows, blocks may get rather empty.  This "combining" keeps the fragmentation under control.

If you "fragmentation" refers to the blocks being scattered around the disk, well, that is not cured by `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  And any block split will use a new block from 'anywhere'.

`UPDATE` is somewhere between `INSERT` (of the text in the row grows) and `DELETE` (if the data shrinks).

(There are many more details that I left out.)

Comment: How comes ?
Won't it provide a nice defragmentation ?

Especially in my case the table is updated a lot on random rows.

Comment: @John - I changed my 1 paragraph answer into 8.